# One author not showing in Author drop down list while editing page

Tags: pages, author, user-roles

USER01 is not showing in Author drop down list while editing a Page if he's in the my custom ROLE "mycustomrole".

If I change his role as an AUTHOR, and add the very same custom and non custom capacities, he's shown in the list.

I created this role programatically, as shown below.

Is there something particular to add in order to see it in my Authors list?

```
function cjg_4cast_addroles(){
    cjg_add_role('mycustomrole','My Custom Role',array(
        array('singular' => 'side-add', 'plural' => 'side-adds'),
        array('singular' => 'partner', 'plural' => 'partners')
        ),
        array(
            'read' => true,
            'upload_files' => true,
            'edit_files' => true,
            'edit_pages' => true,
            'edit_published_pages' => true,
            'publish_pages' => true,
            'delete_pages' => true,
            'delete_private_pages' => true,
            'edit_private_pages' => true,
            'read_private_pages' => true,
            'publish_posts' => true,
            'edit_posts' => true,
            'edit_published_posts' => true,
        )
    );
}

function cjg_add_role($role_name,$role_name_display,$custom_type_slugs,$capabilities){

    foreach($custom_type_slugs as $custom_type_slug){
        $capabilities = array_merge($capabilities,
            cjg_capabilitiesarray_fromslug($custom_type_slug['singular'],$custom_type_slug['plural'])
            );
    }

    add_role( $role_name, $role_name_display, $capabilities);
}

function cjg_capabilitiesarray_fromslug($singular,$plural){

    return array(
        "edit_$singular" => true,
        "read_$singular" => true,
        "delete_$singular" => true,
        "edit_$plural" => true,
        "edit_others_$plural" => true,
        "publish_$plural" => true,
        "read_private_$plural" => true,
    );
}
```

Comment: why a down vote? I still need to find an answer, I found other posts with the same issue and no solution

Comment: I up voted, valid question. Came across a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is provided here: [Users with custom roles not showing in post author select box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91862/users-with-custom-roles-not-showing-in-post-author-select-box)

I tested and it works:

```
to add a level_1 cap to your role.

It's PITA, considering how user levels have been deprecated so long ago, but there you go
```

Comment: I'm taking a plane, I'll copy paste real code later eventually

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but could the issues have to do with spelling "plural" as "plurial"??  I know that you are using it as a variable name in your functions, but you also reference it in the cjg_add_role function...

Comment: thanks. Sorry for the mispel, since I kept to my mistake all along and it's only a variable name, I don't see how it could influence. It could have if I had changed it in some other place, but I didn't know the spelling was wrong