# Users with custom roles not showing in post author select box

Tags: customization, multi-author

I am using a function to create new user roles and delete some defaults. However, they are not showing up in the post author box! Only the admin shows up because they are selected as an admin. Any user with a custom role does not show up. Any idea why this would be happening?

Here is my function:

```
// Add New User Roles
function add_new_roles() {

    // New Roles To Be Added
    $new_roles = array(
        array(
            'role'      => 'senior_pastor',
            'display'   => 'Senior Pastor'
        ),
        array(
            'role'      => 'exec_pastor',
            'display'   => 'Executive Pastor'
        ),
        array(
            'role'      => 'assoc_pastor',
            'display'   => 'Associate Pastor'
        ),
        array(
            'role'      => 'elder',
            'display'   => 'Elder'
        ),
        array(
            'role'      => 'ministry_leader',
            'display'   => 'Ministry Leader'
        )
    );

    foreach($new_roles as $role){
        add_role($role['role'], $role['display'], array(
            'edit_published_posts' => true,
            'upload_files' => true,
            'create_product' => true,
            'publish_posts' => true,
            'delete_published_posts' => true,
            'edit_posts' => true,
            'delete_posts' => true,
            'read' => true
        ));
    }

    // Old Roles To Be Removed
    $old_roles = array(
        'subscriber',
        'contributor',
        'author'
        'editor'
    );

    foreach($old_roles as $role){
        remove_role( $role );
    }
}
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'add_new_roles');
```

Comment: Why would roles show up in the post author box? Only users show up there.

Comment: Sorry, worded my question wrong. Users with custom roles are not showing up.

Comment: Looks like if you log in as one of your new users, they can create posts. Then, when you login as admin again, their names will appear in the author list of the post 'they' created. I'm not sure why these restrictions apply.

Comment: @vancoder I tried this but nothing happend. It still does not show up. I was able to create a post, but it did not save with me as the editor. Weird!

Answer (score 10):

Found a workaround below. I guess it has to do with a bug in the Wordpress core. This will list ALL users in posts, so be cautious.

```
// Filter to fix the Post Author Dropdown
function author_override( $output ) {
    global $post, $user_ID;

    // return if this isn't the theme author override dropdown
    if (!preg_match('/post_author_override/', $output)) return $output;

    // return if we've already replaced the list (end recursion)
    if (preg_match ('/post_author_override_replaced/', $output)) return $output;

    // replacement call to wp_dropdown_users
      $output = wp_dropdown_users(array(
        'echo' => 0,
        'name' => 'post_author_override_replaced',
        'selected' => empty($post->ID) ? $user_ID : $post->post_author,
        'include_selected' => true
      ));

      // put the original name back
      $output = preg_replace('/post_author_override_replaced/', 'post_author_override', $output);

    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'author_override');
```

credit goes to [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/users-missing-from-author-dropdown-after-upgrade)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, indeed, it is a bug, as reported in the ticket [#16841](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16841).

Testing with 3.6-beta3, it's still there... The workaround is, in [scribu's words](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16841#comment:2):

> *[...] to add a* **`level_1`** *cap to your role.*
>
> *It's PITA, considering how user levels have been deprecated so long ago, but there you go.*

And... it works as advertised ;)

---

For reference, these are the places where `wp_dropdown_users` happen in the core:

[image: export, post list table, meta-boxes, users]